# Replace only one string in C++/CLI

Tags: .net, replace, c++-cli

I do have text like:

```
String^ txt="hello kitty hello master and You, hello kitty and other";
String^ txtst="hello kitty";
```

and want to replace only first hello in text.

```
String^ after = spin->Replace(txt,txtst);
```

replace me all of the strings "hello kitty" and I need only one.

Need help :(

Answer (score 2):

Since the built-in [`String::Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx?cs-lang=cpp) will replace all occurrences, I'd write a helper method to replace just the one.

Use [`IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx?cs-lang=cpp) to find the first occurrence of the string, [`SubString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String.Substring.aspx?cs-lang=cpp) to get the portions of the string to the left and right of it, and concatenate them all together with `+` (which gets turned into [`String::Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String.Concat.aspx?cs-lang=cpp) by the compiler).

```
String^ ReplaceOne(String^ s, String^ searchFor, String^ replaceWith)
{
    int index = s->IndexOf(searchFor);
    if (index == -1) return s; // search string was not found.
    return s->SubString(0, index) + replaceWith + s->SubString(index + searchFor->Length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String^ after = spin->Replace(txt,txtst,1);
```

Comment: sorry  - Error 2 error C2661: 'System::String::Replace' : no overloaded function takes 3 arguments

Comment: Try with (gcnew Regex("e"))->Replace(txt,txtst,1) ...with using namespace System::Text::RegularExpressions; included

Answer (score -1):

This will replace the first found string with the specified replacement string.

```
bool replace(std::string& str, const std::string& from, const std::string& to) {
    size_t start_pos = str.find(from);
    if(start_pos == std::string::npos)
        return false;
    str.replace(start_pos, from.length(), to);
    return true;
}

std::string string("hello $name");
replace(string, "$name", "Somename");
```